How to secure a shaft to hollow-shafted motors?
I plan to use a motor similar to this to drive a hollow shaft. If you click the image, the motor has a hollow shaft, so my hollow shaft can slide through.
But I have two problems with this

I'm unsure how to 'lock' my shaft to the female shaft of the motor. Brief googling
tells me that I have to use a keyed shaft. But the problem is that my shaft needs to be hollow (for some cables to pass through). The key will probably just fall into the hollow space. Also, I don't have access to a milling machine, so I can't make the notch on my own
I need my shaft to be placed vertically (so the orientation is like a flag pole, facing the ground). I don't know how to secure it properly to the motor. I'm assuming if I just put the shaft in, it will just slide out? (A few objects will be mounted to the shaft, so I can't purely rely on friction to secure it)

For problem #1, there should be an adapter that can convert the keyed female shaft configuration to a normal shaft, and then I can lock it using a set screw mechanism. But I don't know the search term for it. Or is there a better way to secure the shaft?
For #2, I'm thinking of attaching a pulley to the hollow shaft (this is also used to couple an encoder using a belt drive) and then maybe just resting the pulley on top of a flat bearing, so the whole system will look something like this (sorry for the crude image). However, I'm not sure if this is the best approach.
Are there better alternatives for both of these problems?
I come from an EE background, so I'm not really familiar with these kinds of things.
Any help is appreciated!

The same way you connect solid shafts - with a shaft coupler. There are dozens of different types that vary in rigidity and concentricity and angular misalignment and axial load capacities. Generally, you want to avoid axial loads on electric motor shafts, so the prop shaft is located and supported by it's own thrust bearings.

And you need to decide how before you order the motor and the propshaft so you can specify the desired shaft ends that come with them. Again, there are about a dozen different shaft end provisions that you can choose from like keyways and external splines and internal splines and flats and shoulders.

@DanielHatton, briefly skimming Google, I think the typical usage is like this. However if the drive shaft is hollow, the shaft may not have enough thickness so it falls inside of the shaft like this.

Also, I don't think they sell a shaft with a premade bulging key like you said, just because it's not easy to make it a universal option. If the key extends through the entire shaft length, balance issues may arise.

@PhilSweet Sorry, I don't quite understand how I could use a shaft coupler to connect the hollow shaft to the motor? Also, about your explanations regarding shoulders and thrust bearings, is the concept similar to this diagram? I grabbed it from this site. I assume that the shoulder part is installed by some kind of clamping mechanism?

You choose you shaft coupler type. You specify the motor shaft such that it accepts the coupler type. You specify the prop shaft such that it accepts the coupler type. The motor will have a code number. Part of that code number specifies the shaft lengths, shaft inner diameter, shaft outer diameter, and coupling styles. Your linked image has zero shaft length and keyway. Change that to  a shaft that has enough length to connect to a coupler.

If you are worried about a shaft falling axially, consider that a shaft need not be the same diameter along its axis for large loads. For small loads, a collar might do. Consider thrust bearings for large axial loads.
